# AWK Command print size in mb,kb or gb by finding a file using ls -l

Tags: bash, unix, awk, solaris, ls

I want to get a file size using find command along with size in kb, mb or gb with decimal point of two only.

Desired output:

```
15.04 MB
10MB
10GB
```

I have tried below command but getting error:

```
find /orabackup/EXPDP/ATRUS001 -name "expdp_ATRUS001_04122017_0500.dmp" -exec ls -ltr  {} \;  | awk ' {s+=$5}' '{ split( "B KB MB GB TB PB" , v ); s=1; while( $1>1024 ){ $1/=1024; s++ } printf "%.2f %s", $1, v[s] }'
```

Output:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `{ split( "B KB MB GB TB PB" , v ); s=1; while( $1>1024 ){ $1/=1024; s++ } printf "%.2f %s", $1, v[s] }' for reading (No such file or directory
```

even though file is present in directory giving me above error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: no need of such "long" processing, everything is much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk ' {s+=$5}' '{ split( "B... ?
```

Why have you split the `awk` program into *two* arguments? This is almost certainly what's causing your problem.

It treats the first argument as the `awk` program and the second as the input file. This is supported by your error message, stating "cannot open ***file*** '{ split ...". What you need to do is to provide the `awk` program as a *single* argument.

---

As an aside (though I'm not sure about Solaris), many of the GNU utilities sport a `-h` option to produce human-readable sizes. Have you tried `ls -h` at all?

According to the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5165/ls-1.html), Solaris supports this, though it may not give you the two decimal places you desire.

---

As another aside, I cannot understand why you're trying to *add* the file size to `s` for each line if you're interested in individual sizes. I also can't understand why you're using `$1` for the divisions when this would be the `drwxr-xr-x` part of the `ls` output.

Perhaps you would be better off specifying in more detail what you want to achieve.

The best I can do for now is to provide this as an example:

```
pax> find . -name '[a-z]*' -exec ls -ltr {} ';' | awk 'BEGIN{split("B KB MB GB TB PB EB ZB YB",v)} {s=1;while($5>1024&&s<9){$5/=1024;s++}printf "%6.2f %-2s %s\n",$5,v[s],$9}'
154.00 B  ./etc_ntp.conf
150.00 B  ./input.txt
  1.85 KB ./qq.sh
200.00 B  ./tmp00
```

That seems to be basically what you're trying to do though you'll need to modify the `find` arguments for your specific case (I just grabbed all files starting with a lower-case letter).

It also limits `s` so that you don't run off the end of the array if you have Exabyte-sized files :-)

Breaking it down for readability:

```
BEGIN {
    # Only need do this once, allow for bigger files.
    split("B KB MB GB TB PB EB ZB YB", v)
}
{
    # Select B suffix.
    s=1

    # Need higher suffix, but stop at YB.
    while ($5 > 1024 && s < 9)
    {
        # Divide by 1K, go to next suffix.
        $5 /= 1024
        s++
    }

    # Pretty-print the line.
    printf "%6.2f %-2s %s\n", $5, v[s], $9
}
```

Comment: @Abhinav: if you want to do multiple things in `awk`, you separate them with `;`, not try to do them with another argument. However, see my update, further assistance will need more detail from you on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to find out a file if it is found than i should get its size in kb, mb or gb according to file size

Comment: @Abhinav: then you probably don't want to be adding anything to `s`, just use `$5` directly. I've provided an example which should help you out.

Comment: it works   BACKUP_SIZE=`find $EXPDP_DIR_PATH -name "${BKP_TYPE}_${ORACLE_SID}_${BKP_ST_TIME}*.dmp" -exec ls -ltr {} \; | awk 'BEGIN{split("B KB MB GB TB PB EB ZB YB",v)} {s=1;while($5>1024&&s<9){$5/=1024;s++}printf "%6.2f %s\n",$5,v[s],$9}'`

Answer (score 3):

Short and optimized **`find`** + **`numfmt`** solution:

```
find /your_dirpath -type f -name "filepath" -printf "%s\n" | numfmt --to=iec --format='%.2fB'
```

- `-printf "%s\n"` - print file size
- `numfmt ...` - convert numbers from/to human-readable strings

---

Example output:

```
3.70MB
24.27MB
38.16MB
1.76MB
```